# Different ways to get summaries with data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

```
temp <- data.table(fir=c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "D"), sec=c(1,1,1,1,2,2))

 fir sec
  A   1
  B   1
  B   1
  C   1
  A   2
  D   2
```

If I want to get a summary by the "sec" column, for example just counting the number of occurences. I can try...

method a)

```
 temp[,.N, by=sec]


  sec N
  1:   1 4
  2:   2 2
```

We get as many of rows as different levels we have at "sec".

method b)

```
 temp[,Num:=.N, by=sec]
```

Same summary but keeping all the columns and the same number of rows.

```
 fir sec Num
  A   1   4
  B   1   4
  B   1   4
  C   1   4
  A   2   2
  D   2   2
```

But...
How can get a result like method a) but specifying the name of the new column?  I mean without needing to explicitly changing the names later.
I've tried with Num=.N  without the := but it doesn't work.

How can get a result like method b) but without explicitly writing the name of the new column and without modifying the original datatable? (like ave())
I mean running something like this

```
 temp[,.N, by=sec]
```

but getting

```
 fir sec  N
  A   1   4
  B   1   4
  B   1   4
  C   1   4
  A   2   2
  D   2   2
```

Comment: do you mean `temp[,.(Num=.N), by=sec]` ?

Comment: or, @mtoto, that would be the answer for the first question, thanks. What about the second one, getting a long result without modifying the original dataset?

Comment: For the second question, you could do `temp[, c(.SD, .N), by=sec]`. Note that use of `:=` is more efficient as it does not involve making a copy of the data.table (assignment by reference). The other methods involve copies.

Comment: How is the the syntax if you want to assign two things at once? for example Num=.N and the mean or a proportion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep`

```
temp[,.(Num = rep(.N, .N)), by=sec]
```

---

If we need to get the other variables, one option is `on`

```
temp[temp[, .(Num = .N), by=sec], on = .(sec)]
```

Comment: I try to avoid joins because they use to be slower and need much more memory.

Comment: @skan In that case the `:=` will be more efficient, but before that I make a copy of the data i.e. `tempO <- copy(temp); temp[, Num := .N, by = sec]`

Comment: How is the the syntax if you want to assign two things at once? for example Num=.N and the mean or a proportion.

Comment: @skan Try `temp[temp[, .(Num = .N, Mean = mean(col)), by = sec], on = .(sec)]`